# Create VM of image in google compute node.js

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine

I can create a VM in google compute in node.js via:

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();
const zone = compute.zone('us-central1-a');
const [vm, operation] = await zone.createVM(vmName, { os: 'ubuntu' });
```

But how can I create a VM of an Image?

Comment: You will need to specify the **config** JSON. Look for the key **sourceImage**. Examples on this page: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/compute/latest/Zone.html#createVM

Comment: great, that was I looking for. thanks